# React Router 4.1.1 does not render when I click on a <Link>

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I am simply trying to click on a  component and have react rerender what is needed to be rendered. But I simply can't archive that. This is what I have so far:

Index.js (This is where I tried to store all my routes)

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import Main from "./pages/index/main.js";
import Login from "./pages/signin/signin.js";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch} from "react-router-dom";
ReactDOM.render(
  <div>
    <Router>
      <Switch>
        <Route exact  path="/" render={()=> <Main />}/>
        <Route path="/login" render={()=> <Login />}/>
      </Switch>
    </Router>
  </div>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

Header.JS ( Where I have the Link tags setup )

```
import React from "react";
import style from "./../acc/css/navbar.css";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Link} from "react-router-dom";
export default class Header extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <Router>
    <section className={style.nav} id="nav">
            <ul>
        <li><Link to="/">Home</Link></li>
        <li><Link to="/login">Login</Link></li>
            </ul>
        </section>
        </Router>
        );
    }
}
```

As of now, when I manually go to `/`, it renders the `Main` component, and when I manually go to `/login`, it renders the `Login` component.

However, when I click on the `<Link>`  component, it doesn't render, it just changes the URL to `/login` or vise versa.

I was wondering if there is any solution to this issue?

## Edit 1

Main.js code

```
import React from "react";
//import compunts
import Header from "./../header.js";
import Qoute from "./qoute.js";
import Grades from "./grades.js";

export default class Main extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
      <div id="continor">
                <Header />
                <Qoute />
                <Grades />
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Signin.js

```
    import React from "react";
    import Header from "./../header.js";
    import Qoute from "./qoute.js";
    import Form from "./form.js";
    export default class Login extends React.Component {
        render() {
            return(
          <div>
          <Header />
            <section id="info">
              <div className="containor">
                <div className="row">
                  <Qoute />
                  <Form />
                </div>
              </div>
            </section>
          </div>
            );
        }
    }
```

For clarification, I have tried the

```
<Route exact path="/" component={Main}/>
```

and that still doesn't work. Any solutions?

Comment: Can you try `<Route exact  path="/" component={Main}/>`

Comment: same results :(

Comment: You only need to define Router once in your parent component btw. Also instead of "render={()=> <Login />}" in your routes, use "component={Home}".  Can you include the code for your main and home components please?

Comment: I have tried that before I only did "render" is when I saw an answer somewhere that suggested that which both solutions didn't work. I will edit my question and include the main and login component. I am not sure what you mean by the home component!

Comment: Some components block updates. If you use react-redux or React.PureComponent you must use withRouter() to propagate updates. Documentation: https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router/docs/api/withRouter.md https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router/docs/guides/blocked-updates.md Related question:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44823590/react-router-4-doesnt-update-ui-when-clicking-link/44841085#44841085

Answer (score 0):

Now you have `<Link>` elements inside the `<Router>` tag. You have to remove this `<Router>` and links starts works.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your Header.js as,

```
import React from "react";
import style from "./../acc/css/navbar.css";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Link} from "react-router-dom";
export default class Header extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
    <section className={style.nav} id="nav">
            <ul>
        <li><Link to="/">Home</Link></li>
        <li><Link to="/login">Login</Link></li>
            </ul>
        </section>
        );
    }
}
```

And click on a link it shows.