# React Router does not update View

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am beginning to work with React and I have an issue understanding how to make [react-router](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/guides/quick-start) work.

In my project, I created an `App.js` file that exports a simple render function:

```
export default class App extends React.Component {
    render () {
        return <Router>
            <div>
                <Link to="/connected">Login</Link>
                <Link to="/">Home</Link>

                <Route path="/connected" component={Connected}/>
                <Route exact path="/" component={LoginPage}/>

            </div>
        </Router>
    }
}
```

Of course, on the top of the file, I import two components: `Connected` and `LoginPage` and a bunch of other components:

```
import React from 'react'

import {
    HashRouter as Router,
    Route,
    Link
} from 'react-router-dom'

import LoginPage from './pages/LoginPage'
import Connected from './pages/Connected'
```

My components are quite simple:

```
import React from 'react'

export default class LoginPage extends React.Component {

    render () {
        return  <div>
            Hello World 1
        </div>
    }
}
```

And pretty much the same for the second component.

My problem is:

When I click on a `<Link to="/">Home</Link>`, the page is not updated with the `LoginPage` component. But if I refresh the page, the `LoginPage` components appears. If I click on `<Link to="/connected">Login</Link>`, the router does not update the page and I also need to refresh completely the page to display the right component.

**What am I doing wrong? What other informations would you need to help me resolve my problem?**

Comment: This is just a guess. Replace `HashRouter` with `BrowserRouter`

Comment: I tried the BrowserRouter but it did not work either. I decided to use the HashRouter because my dev server is only serving the `/` URL

Comment: React Router version you are using? I assume you are using version 4.

Comment: I'm using `"react-router-dom": "^4.1.1"`

Comment: Looks like I'm not the only one having the issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43836434/react-router-4-1-1-does-not-render-when-i-click-on-a-link

Comment: I have tried your code through Create React App and `Link` works smoothly. Show your package.json. How are you deploying your React app? Have you tried more than one browser?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Copy this into 'Package.json' > 'dependencies': `"react-router": "^2.4.0",`

Then do `npm install`

Once done this:

Try this:

First Component (Routes, it is App.jsx) (Maybe you need to change routes of imports)

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Router, Route, browserHistory, Redirect } from 'react-router';

import LoginPage from './pages/LoginPage'
import Connected from './pages/Connected'

ReactDOM.render(
    <Router history={browserHistory}>
        <Route path="/" component={LoginPage}/>
        <Route path="/connected" component={Connected}/>
    </Router>
    , document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Second component (Home):

```
import React from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router';

export default class Home extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return(
            <div>
                <h1> This is HomePage </h1>
                <h3> Click to go HomePage </h3>
                <Link to="/">Home</Link>
                <h3> Click to go Connected </h3>
                <Link to="/connected">Connected</Link>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Third component (Connected):

```
import React from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router';

export default class Connected extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return(
            <div>
                <h1> This is ConnectedPage </h1>
                <h3> Click to go HomePage </h3>
                <Link to="/">Home</Link>
                <h3> Click to go Connected </h3>
                <Link to="/connected">Connected</Link>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: You were kind of right with the versions, I was using react 0.14.x and updating to 15.x.x solved the issue

Comment: Glad to have helped you.