# react-router 4 doesn't update UI when clicking <Link>

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-v4

I am writing a small app with a navigation bar and 5 routes using `react-router-dom 4.1.1`. When I click on a link in the navigation bar, the URL in the Firefox address bar updates, but the page displayed does not change. However, if I enter the address of a subpage in the address bar, the correct page is displayed.

app.js:

```
render(
    <Provider store={store}>
        <HashRouter>
            <MainContainer />
        </HashRouter>
    </Provider>,
    document.querySelector('.app')
);
```

Main.js:

```
render() {
    return (
        <div className="main">
            <Message message= {this.props.message} />
            <NavigationBar />
            <Switch>
                <Route exact path="/" component={HomePage}></Route>
                <Route path="/classify" component={ClassifyPage}></Route>
                <Route path="/admin" component={AdminPage}></Route>
                <Route path="/users" component={UsersPage}></Route>
                <Route path="/help" component={HelpPage}></Route>
            </Switch>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: can you share your navbar ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It seems some components, like react-redux containers using connect(), block updates. The problem was solved using withRouter():

```
const MainContainer = withRouter(connect(
        mapStateToProps,
        mapDispatchToProps
      )(Main));
```

Documentation: https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router/docs/api/withRouter.md

Comment: Did this solve your problem because I use the `withRouter` wrapper just like you did here, but I'm still experiencing the same problem?

Comment: Yes, this solved my problem. Do you use `withRouter` whenever you use `connect`?

Comment: Yeah I do, I even tried removing connect but it's still behaving the came way.

Comment: Perhaps you use some other component that breaks the update chain?

Comment: @DanielBarde Did you manage to solve your issue? I am also having the same exact problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

I have the same error, but when I use withRouter, nothing changes. In my case, the reason of error is putting the `<Link>` elements into the `<Router>` tag.

```
<Router>
<Link to="something"></Link>
</Router>
```

Beware of that error, is very hard to diagnose! To fix this, just remove unneccesary `<Router>` wrapper

Comment: Thanks for this hint. I have the same error as above explained, but there is no unneccesary `<Router>`.in my code  :-(

Comment: You are the best!!

Answer (score 0):

Erik Winge almost the right. 
As I understand component where you enter  you need to wrap your Component with withRouter.

So, to fix this you need to add:

```
...
Main = withRouter(Main);
...
export default Main;
...
```